Fixing random small-caps glyphs in figure caption label
I am loading the inter package to configure my font in my class file:
\RequirePackage[sfdefault,light,semibold]{inter}

I also load the caption package and a few others.
This works fine for the English version of my document:


But when I enable the fr version of my class which loads babel and sets up other localization
\RequirePackage[french]{babel}
\RequirePackage[autolanguage]{numprint}
\RequirePackage{hyphenat}
\hyphenation{mate-mática recu-perar}

I get strange small-caps characters randomly in my figure and table labels. The captions themselves demonstrate that the character is available in the font.


I have tried setting the label text myself in case the strange character is being read from babel somehow, but that did not fix it. I also tried setting different font configuration options like sf, bf, etc. to manipulate the caption label typeface just  to see if it could cause any change, but the strange small-caps are still present.
If someone has any ideas of next steps I can try to debug this problem, I would really appreciate it. Thank you!

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault,light,semibold]{inter}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
  fff
  \caption{La structure organisationnelle}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[h]
  ttt
  \caption{Nomenclature des evironnements}
\end{table}

aaa
\end{document}



please provide a small test document that shows the problem, not just disconnected fragments

I did it this time

Thank you, I just prepared one, but realized you were faster when I went to edit. :) I appreciate it.

I notice as well that the l character displays very differently when compiled with pdflatex vs lualatex. The glyph used with lualatex is the correct one for Inter, I think. I am not sure why this is happening, but I have updated my build process to use lualatex because of this. You can see the difference between the l in my screenshot and yours.

with lualtex you can see that private use area positions are being used to access the "correct" small caps glyphs but some characters seem to be missing from that mapping and you get the normal lowercase.  My screenshot is with pdflatex, with lualatex you get  similar but different output (it uses the original otf font not the remapped subsets)

I added some luatex logging to my answer

The example can be simplified to
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault,light,semibold]{inter}

\begin{document}
\showoutput
\textsc{TABLE table}

\end{document}


There isn't a lot you can do from TeX other than avoid small caps or change the font. The lowercase letters in the TLF variant seem incorrectly chosen
The above image os pdflatex output but if you use lualatex you see similar but the log is more informative
.....\TU/Inter(0)/m/sc/10 
....\TU/Inter(0)/m/sc/10 b
....\TU/Inter(0)/m/sc/10 
....\TU/Inter(0)/m/sc/10 e
....\glue(\spaceskip) 2.8125 plus 1.40625 minus 0.9375
....\TU/Inter(0)/m/sc/10 
....\TU/Inter(0)/m/sc/10 
....\TU/Inter(0)/m/sc/10 

here you see that the correct small caps hav ebeen pulled from the private use U+EE.. block but b and e for some reason fail to map to that range so produce the standard lowercase.

If you open the Inter-Light.otf font with a font editor (fontforge here), you see that a lot of caracters are missing from in the smcp feature table.  You could complain to the font maintainer.  Otherwise, with babel-french you can avoid small caps in captions by adding \frenchsetup{SmallCapsFigTabCaptions=false} in the preamble after loading babel.

@DanielFlipo thank you for pointing me to babel-french as the cause for why small-caps was being triggered at all. I did not understand why this was happening since it does not happen in in the English version. I didn't realize that the French package did this. The \frenchsetup command you provide here and described in the last paragraph of Section 3.2 here does exactly what I want.

@jachou-ndaq sorry I thought you realised that as you had added french in your MWE, I  should have mentioned it. I had simplified the example dropping babel but then used \textsc directly as captions etc don't use small caps by default in the standard classes.
